# ExoPlayer HLS stream AD insertion

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, google-ima

I have HLS stream. When I trying insert VAST tag into stream :

1. exoplayer not show AD with any errors and warnings in logcat
2. exoplayer throwing exception, and after re-init with HlsMediaSource.Factory(..) works well

How i build ExoPlayer instance:

```
private fun initPlayer() {
        adsLoader = ImaAdsLoader.Builder(requireContext())
            .setAdEventListener { adEvent ->
                // SOME LISTENER
            }
            .build()

        val httpDataSource = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().createDataSource().apply {
            setRequestProperty("Referer", "*some referer*")
        }

        // Set up the factory for media sources, passing the ads loader and ad view providers.
        val httpDataSourceFactory = DataSource.Factory { httpDataSource }

        val mediaSourceFactory: MediaSource.Factory =
        DefaultMediaSourceFactory(httpDataSourceFactory)
            .setLocalAdInsertionComponents(
                { unusedAdTagUri: MediaItem.AdsConfiguration? -> adsLoader }
            ) { //some view for ad
                binding.unsafe.adView 
            }


        // some buffering settings
        val loadControlBuilder = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
        loadControlBuilder.setBufferDurationsMs(
            AppConstants.Player.PLAYER_BUFFER_DURATION,
            AppConstants.Player.PLAYER_BUFFER_DURATION,
            DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS,
            DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS
        )
        // init player
        playerInstance =
            ExoPlayer.Builder(
                requireContext(),
                DefaultRenderersFactory(requireContext()),
                mediaSourceFactory,
                DefaultTrackSelector(requireContext()),
                loadControlBuilder.build(),
                DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(requireContext()).build(),
                DefaultAnalyticsCollector(Clock.DEFAULT)
            ).setSeekBackIncrementMs(AppConstants.Player.PLAYER_SEEK_FORWARD)
                .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(AppConstants.Player.PLAYER_SEEK_FORWARD)
                .build()
    }
```

How i setup my player for HLS stream:

```
private fun setupExoPlayer(source: String, adLink: String? = null) {
        if (playerInstance == null) initPlayer()

        binding {
            player.playerView.player = playerInstance
            adsLoader?.setPlayer(playerInstance)
            player.playerView.subtitleView?.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        val adsConfig = adLink?.let { MediaItem.AdsConfiguration.Builder(Uri.parse(adLink)).build() }

        val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(source)
            .setAdsConfiguration(adsConfig)
            .build()

        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()

        val hlsMediaSource: HlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(mediaItem)

        playerInstance?.apply {
            setMediaSource(hlsMediaSource)
            prepare()
            addListener(playerErrorHandler) // adding some listeners here
            playWhenReady = true
        }
    }
```

How i insert AD VAST tag after some playing time, difference in setMediaSource or setMediaItem of this source:

```
private fun injectAdIntoExoPlayer(adLink: String) {
        val adsConfig = MediaItem.AdsConfiguration.Builder(Uri.parse(adLink)).build()
            val mediaItemWithAd = playerInstance?.currentMediaItem?.buildUpon()?.setAdsConfiguration(
                adsConfig
            )?.build()
    
            mediaItemWithAd?.let {
                val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                val hlsMediaSource: HlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(mediaItemWithAd)
    

                // - first case behavior (not showing ad !!!)
                playerInstance?.setMediaSource(hlsMediaSource) 
                // - second case behavior (showing ad !!!)
                // playerInstance?.setMediaItem(hlsMediaSource.mediaItem) 
            }
        }
```

In second case behaviour exoplayer throws this. Same exceptions I have when init player without HlsMediaSource factory:

```
 E/LoadTask: Unexpected exception loading stream
      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: size=9400 offset=0 byteCount=-940
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Util.checkOffsetAndCount(Util.java:30)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:368)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.readInternal(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:768)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.read(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:478)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.read(StatsDataSource.java:92)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.readFromUpstream(DefaultExtractorInput.java:291)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.read(DefaultExtractorInput.java:68)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor.fillBufferWithAtLeastOnePacket(TsExtractor.java:433)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor.read(TsExtractor.java:323)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.BundledHlsMediaChunkExtractor.read(BundledHlsMediaChunkExtractor.java:67)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.feedDataToExtractor(HlsMediaChunk.java:473)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:437)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:394)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)


 E/LoadTask: Unexpected exception loading stream
      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: size=8192 offset=0 byteCount=-33
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Util.checkOffsetAndCount(Util.java:30)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:368)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.readInternal(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:768)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.read(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:478)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.read(StatsDataSource.java:92)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:80)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:288)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:351)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:180)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:172)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:193)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.checkPlaylistHeader(HlsPlaylistParser.java:296)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:259)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:68)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:176)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

So i need inject my AD Vast tag with exoplayer:extension-ima dependency without handling player error and reiniting with **setMediaSource** method and without my AD link